# Finding a more explicit way to express a coefficient in this summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

I am sorry about the vague title, i really don't know how else to ask the question. So i have came up with the following:

$$
1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{v=0}^{n} \frac{x^{n-k+1} T_{n+1,k+1} (-1)^{n-v+1}}{(x-v)v!(n-v)!}
$$

Where as $T_{n+1,k+1}$ is the coefficient that i am trying to find a more explicit definition of. I have come to find that $T_{n,k}$ holds some values such as:

$$
T_{n,1} = 1
$$

$$
T_{n,2} = \frac{-n(n-1)}{2}
$$

$$
T_{n,n} = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!
$$

And if $2<c<n$

$$
T_{n,c} = T_{n-1,c} - (n-1)T_{n-1,c-1}
$$

These properties are good and all but i don't like how there is a recurrence relation. If there is a recursive definition should i just be satisfied and leave it at that? Is there no way for me to find out a more explicit way to express this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you recursive definition I would say that you found the [signed Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) with only the order changed :
$$T_{n,c}=s(n,\,n+1-c)= (-1)^{c-1}\left[\matrix {n\\n+1-c}\right]$$
(concerning your first equality I obtain $-1$ at the left)

Further references : Gould ["Combinatorial Numbers and Associated Identities" vol $7$](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.7.PDF).
the recommended Book "Concrete mathematics" by Graham&Knuth&Patashnik.

[pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) scripts used :

> t(n,c)=if(c<=2,if(c<=1,1,-n*(n-1)/2),if(c>=n,(-1)^(n-1)*(n-1)!,t(n-1,c)-(n-1)*t(n-1,c-1)))
>   ss(n)=sum(k=0,n,sum(v=0,n,(x^(n-k+1)*stirling(n+1,n+2-(k+1)) *(-1)^(n-v+1))/((x-v)*v!*(n-v)!)))
>   \\we may replace t(n,c) by  stirling(n,n+1-c) in the following line 
>   for(n=1,6,print(vector(n,c,t(n,c))))

[1]
[1, -1]
[1, -3, 2]
[1, -6, 11, -6]
[1, -10, 35, -50, 24]
[1, -15, 85, -225, 274, -120]

Comment: Thank you, you actually indirectly solved a big problem for me. If you look on the wiki page, where they have the sum for the falling factorial, that is the same thing as $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{n-k+1} T_{n+1,k+1} (-1)^{n-v+1}$ can anything be said about my other summation, i came up with that as well. it is the partial fraction decomposition of a reciprocal falling factorial.

Comment: Sorry @EricLawson I didn't find quickly a reference (nor a proof) for the first equation (well with $-1$ at the left) but I would bet you found one! Identities concerning Stirling numbers are numerous as you may see in my added references ('google' the second one!) Excellent continuation anyway,

Comment: Well, i tried to solve for your answer and did the following:
$$
|s(n,2)| = [{n \choose c}] = (n-1)! H_{n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
Therefore with your solution:
$
[{{n+1-2} \choose 2}] = (n-2)!\frac{1}{(n-2)!} [{n+1 \choose 2}] = [{n-1 \choose 2}]
$
Which seems right so far. perhaps i can make something else from it. note: those binomial coefficients are a failed attempt of the notation you were using, just ignore those.

Comment: @Eric: really sorry for the confusion created here (I reversed the first ($n$) parameter instead of the second one ($c$). I joined my scripts to avoid further errors.

Comment: I'm going to post a question on how to prove this expression, i have been trying for quite a while, but it seems nearly impossible You seem knowledgeable you should try it out.

Comment: @EricLawson: my first idea would be to compute the sum over $k$ this returns a [quotient of $\Gamma$ functions for W.Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%28%28x-k-1%29*%28k-1%29%21*%28n-k%29%21%29%2Ck%3D1..n%29).

Comment: The sum over $m$ contains clearly the falling factorial you were talking about previously $\,\displaystyle \sum_{u=1}^n x^u\,s(n,u)\;$ (for $u:=n-m+1$). With a little luck, and the accessory fact that the result should be $1$ ;-), we may hope that these two results (both quotient of $\Gamma$ functions) and possibly the functions of $n$ I didn't consider will cancel. I encourage you to provide an answer yourself (this is recommended practice here!) should all this work... Excellent continuation !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18543/discussion-between-eric-lawson-and-raymond-manzoni).